# Is there any way to do lens correction in Adobe Photoshop 7?

Tags: software, photoshop, distortion

I am walking through a tutorial for Photoshop but at one point they choose "Lens Correction" in the Filter --> Distort menu.  I am on Photoshop 7 so I don't have this.

Is there anyway to do lens correction in this version of Adobe Photoshop?

Answer (score 2):

[PTLens](http://epaperpress.com/ptlens/index.html) includes a standalone program which will do lens corrections, which should allow you to do what you want.

However I don't know whether the PTLens plugin will work in PS7 or not.

Using PTLens standalone would involve saving your image as a (recommended) 16-bit TIFF and invoking PTLens on that image file outside of Photoshop before continuing your Photoshop work.

Comment: It runs as a standalone and as a PS plugin compatible with PS beginning with version 6 and all versions of PS/Elements.